# Why is it "gains to trade" instead of "gains in trade" or "gains of trade"?

Tags: prepositions, parsing

> Standard economic theory (i.e., the Heckscher-Ohlin model) provides the sharp
>   prediction that with perfect factor mobility, **gains to trade** flow to the abundant factors, such as unskilled labor in developing countries. (source: a paper by economist Petia Topalova)

I am having a hard time parsing this sentence. It seems to me it should be a clause after "with perfect factor mobility". Is "gain" a noun here? And is "gains to trade" the subject of that clause? If so, why is the preposition "to" used instead of "of" or "in"? I have looked at dictionaries and found sentences that use "gain in" and "gain of" but not "gains to".

Answer (score 1):

**to** can express an attribute relation.

> This is the key **to** that door.

You could paraphrase here as "gains in trade" or "gains in respect to trade".

The preposition can also express the notion of **accrual**.

> When Microsoft closely coupled their software products to their operating system, they saw significant gains *to* their market share.

That is, the market share accrued unto itself significant gains, i.e. it grew.